# How to Place an Image Inside a Styled Button

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8, styles

I wanted to experiment with a download I found on create.msdn.com which is a glass button style for regular buttons. I like the effect it gives when a user presses it, but also I think it would be a nice feature to be able to add an image instead of text as the button's content. For an image, I was planning on using a default Windows Phone Icon from the icon set available with the SDK. How might I do this though so that the effects remain in tact, and the content can be the icon?

The style is as follows

```
<Style x:Key="GlassButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>

                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                </vsm:VisualState>

                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="glow" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" 
                                                                  Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>

                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value=".55"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4">
                            <Border x:Name="border" Background="#7F000000" BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.507*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.493*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Border Opacity="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="glow" Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <RadialGradientBrush>
                                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.702" ScaleY="2.243"/>
                                                        <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                                                        <TranslateTransform X="-0.368" Y="-0.152"/>
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#B28DBDFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#008DBDFF" Offset="1"/>
                                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="shine" Width="Auto" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.494,0.889" StartPoint="0.494,0.028">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#99FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#33FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And here is my button

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="test" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" 
                    Style="{StaticResource GlassButton}">                
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem, Button is a content control. In other words, you can do something like this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" 
                Style="{StaticResource GlassButton}" Height="60" Width="200">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="/Images/someImage.png" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this in my recent side project:

```
<Button Click="OpenFolder" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
        ToolTip="Open Folder (CTRL+O)">
    <Image Width="25" Height="20" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="Resources/Images/appbar.folder.ellipsis.png" />
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

Displaying image instead of text, inside a styled button. This work for me, hope will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can set image as background in button using following style
<Style x:Key="BtnStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="110"/>

        <!--FontFamily="Cambria" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold"-->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Background"  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" >
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/barCode.png"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter
                              x:Name="contentPresenter"                               
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"                               
                              Margin="-10 0 0 0"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Fill="Transparent"  Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Margin="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


////This is the code in above BtnStyle where you can change ImageSource of your button's background image
<Border.Background>
  <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/barCode.png"/>
 </Border.Background> 


<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="test" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" 
Style="{StaticResource BtnStyle}">                
</Button>
```